# Set TCP ECN on a socket (C Linux)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, congestion-control

Is it there a way to set TCP ECN on an unprivileged TCP socket in a C linux program?

Does any congestion algorythm that can be set through setsockopt() involve ECN?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8394625/3288910).

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate - the key is unprivileged and also the implied per-socket and setsockopt() behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no and technically yes (but based on the question it won't help and I don't think it is yes to what you wanted to ask).

ECN is turned on by echoing 1 to /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_ecn. See 
[ip_sysctl.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt). By default it should be 2 which enables ECN when the peer requests it, but does not initiate requests for it. To set this would require "privileges" and can't be done via a socket so the 1st answer is no.

Congestion algorithms may be set on a per socket basis and may involve ECN, trivially the default one does. So *technically*, yes. But even though the congestion algorithms may involve ECN, the code in tcp_input.c and tcp_output.c makes it clear that without the sysctl flag set, it won't use it, so it won't help.

See the very good information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23314322/5226168)